# Merging multiple bytea rows based on id

Tags: database, postgresql, subquery

I'm working with a postgres database where I need to merge multiple rows into a row based on ID.

```
ID  | A  | B  | C  |
--------------------
1   | x  |    |    |
1   | x  | y  |    |
2   | x  |    | z  |
3   |    | y  |    |
3   |    |    | z  |
```

A, B and C are bytea columns.

I need to merge it as follows:

```
ID  | A  | B  | C  |
--------------------
1   | x  | y  |    |
2   | x  |    | z  |
3   |    | y  | z  |
```

The problem occurs when I do GROUP BY on ID, as I'm not able to find a appropriate aggregate function for bytea columns.

Comment: Looks like you have to do your own aggregate function  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xaggr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do it with sub queries

```
WITH allID as ( 
    SELECT distinct ID
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
   ID, 
  (SELECT A FROM yourTable yt where yt.ID = ai.ID ORDER BY A LIMIT 1) as A,
  (SELECT B FROM yourTable yt where yt.ID = ai.ID ORDER BY B LIMIT 1) as B,
  (SELECT C FROM yourTable yt where yt.ID = ai.ID ORDER BY C LIMIT 1) as C
FROM allID as ai
```